# How to break words in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've been working on a text editor tutorial for practice and have come across a problem with the iframe. If one were to spam a character without having any spaces, the iframe will create a scroll bar rather than break the word. How can I fix this so that the text wrapping acts similar to a text area? Edit: For example if someone were to write "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" it would force a horizontal scroll bar. I would rather that words longer than the width of the iframe be broken so that it may fit.

```
<body onLoad = "iframe()">


<h1 class="titlehead"> Title:</h1>
<form method = "post" action = "submit.php" id = "rtf">
<div class="threadpostcont">
    <input type="text" name="title" class="titleinput" placeholder="Title here"></input>
    <br>
    <input id = "bolder" class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "Bold" onclick = "bold()">
    <input class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "Italicize" onclick = "italic()">
    <input class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "Underline" onclick = "underline()">
    <input class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "Font Size" onclick = "fontsize()">
    <input class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "Colour" onclick = "fontcolor()">  
    <input class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "Strike Through" onclick = "strike()">
    <input class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "Link" onclick = "link()">
    <input class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "Unlink" onclick = "unlink()">
    <input class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "Picture" onclick = "picture()">
    <input class = "textbut" type = "button" value = "List" onclick = "unlist()">
    <br>
    <textarea name = "textarea" id = "textarea" style = "display: none;"></textarea>
    <iframe name = "editor" id = "editor" class="theframe"></iframe>
    <br><br>
    <input type = "button" onclick = "formsubmit()" value = "Post" id="threadsend">
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
```

And the script: I left out the functions for changing to text make the code more clear.

```
function iframe(){
editor.document.designMode = 'on';}
```

Comment: Show an actual example of content that causes the problem described, and specify *how* the text may be divided into lines. Textarea formatting is very special. If you really want to have words broken at arbitrary points without indicating in any way that a word has been broken, you should include this is in the question.

Comment: Added in an edit. Yes I would like strings longer than the width of the iframe to be broken.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using CSS3 `word-break`property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: You should not brea k words, under any normal conditions. And w3schools is still a poor reference.